# Jira - two different lists in transition

Tags: automation, jira

I have the problem that the value "x" is set in a select box in a preselection for a Jira ticket. Depending on this, I would like to show one list with checkboxes and hide another in a later transition.  Depending on the value of the select box.

Is this possible, possibly also via the Script Runner or Project Automation?

I have already tried to query the values via the Script Runner, but this did not work.